# CSS for image next to block of text ON MOBILE

Tags: html, image, css-float

What's the best way to do this?

I have a full-width row (320px). 160px is an image on one side, the other 160px is reserved for text. Is it a simple float, or is there a less destructive way?

```
        <div class="two-up_img u-pull-right">
            <figure>
                <img src="../img/img.jpg">
            </figure>
        </div>

        <div class="two-up_info">
            <div class="inner">
                <h4 class="highlight">Rob</h4>
                <div class="small">
                    <p>Landing Page</p>
                    <p>Brand Identity</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
.two-up_info {
    height: 160px;
    background: #fff;
}

.two-up_info .inner {
    text-align: center;
    position: relative;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}

.two-up_img {
    max-width: 50%;
}
```

I'm using a framework called Skeleton (http://getskeleton.com/), which is where the `u-pull-right` comes from. It floats an element to the right.

Answer (score 0):

You want to wrap your html in a parent `div` and apply the styling `clear: both` to that parent `div`.

See this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5gkzh2pa/

Or, if you are not concerned about supporting old browsers, take a look at flexbox: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: did this help you?